# DataFrame boolean indexing using .loc

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a series (business_day) which was generated via `isin` in order to create the series with dtype: bool:

```
Series: 0 True
1 True
2 True
...
563 False
566 False
Name: Date, dtpye: bool
```

I then tried to update another array by using:

```
myArray.ix[business_day]
```

and

```
myArray.loc[business_day]
```

where

```
myArray:
DataFrame: Date Epoch Value
0 2016-05-17 2016-05-17 11:30:00 12345
1 2016-05-17 2016-05-17 11:31:00 6789.7
2 2016-05-17 2016-05-17 11:32:00 123.45
```

The aim is to modify only myArray whereby the lines are "True" as per the business_day series. However the code used above has no effect. Where am I going wrong here?

Comment: What do you mean by no effect (assuming you did assign the result of `myArray.loc[business_day]` to some variables as it doesn't work `in_place`)? if you print `myArray.loc[business_day]`, does it show the same number of rows as before?

Comment: Exactly: the same number of rows therefore the line of code above (myArray.loc[business_day]) made no difference.

Answer (score 1):

Assign the result as it doesn't modify the original `DataFrame`:

```
myarray = myarray.loc[business_day]
```

Comment: Such a dumb mistake...yes it did the trick! Thanks, enjoy the weekend.

Comment: Which one? The `.values` shouldn't be necessary.

Comment: Ok added back to the answer for completeness. glad it was helpful.